# WebStorm skip find occurrence hotkey

Tags: webstorm

I've recently moved from Sublime Text 3 to WebStorm 11 and I am missing a key feature when selecting occurrences of the same selection:
**The ability to skip a selection (with a hotkey).**

#### Use case

```
const item = { itemValue: 1, itemName: 'one' };
console.log(item.itemValue);
```

Selecting the first `item` and pressing `Ctrl + G` (Mac) will start selecting the `item` occurrences inside the object properties, and I want to select only the `item` right after the `const` and inside the `console.log`. Essentially, I want to skip the two `item` occurrences inside the object.

This is a dummy use case to illustrate the point, I know I can Refactor > Rename it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highlight the text you want to edit:

[image: first selection]

`Ctrl+G` will find the next occurrence of the highlighted text and select it:

[image: second selection]

`Cmd+G` will drop the current selection and select the next one:

[image: third selection]

`Cmd+G` one more time will drop the current selection and select the next one:

[image: final selection]

For anyone that has a different Keymap:

`Cmd+G`: "Find Next / Move to Next Occurrence"

`Ctrl+G`: "Add Selection for Next Occurrence"

Comment: `Ctrl+G` effectively binds the selected text to "find". So if you select "item",  hit `Ctrl+G` and then deselect the text, `Cmd+G` will still find the next occurrence of "item".

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the only solution I found is using Find:

1. Select the text and press `Cmd + F` (the find bar will open with the selected text as a search)
2. Press `Cmd + G` to select the next occurrence
3. Press `Enter` to skip it (will select the next occurrence)
4. Press `Enter` again
5. Press `Esc` to exit the find context

And now the desired items are selected and ready for editing.

At least it's doable, but I'd expect a hotkey to just skip the current occurrence.

Comment: You don't have to enter the find bar. `Ctrl + G` to get your current selection, `Cmd + G`x2 to skip the next two, and you now have the two instances of the variable `item` selected.

Comment: @cdbajorin Wow, that really works, couldn't find it documented anywhere.   Add an answer and I"ll accept it.